# Restore Win7 from system backup into virtual machine on Win8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, system-restore, windows-7-backup

I have a backup ('Windows Image Backup') of a Windows 7 system, and I'd like to be able to run this system in a virtual machine on Windows 8.

Obviously I've got the default VM runner, Hyper-V, but I'll happily use any other free package.

Can I do this? How?

Comment: Sure.  I am sure there are programs that will convert a Windows Image Backup image into a virtual machine.  Furthermore there are tools to take a physical computer and turn it into a virtual machine, for instance, VMWare has this capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Windows 7 on the VM.
2. In the start menu search box, type `recovery` and press enter.
3. Click `Advanced recovery methods`.
4. Click `Use a system image you created earlier to recover your computer`, and then follow the steps.

Comment: I'm installing Windows 8 in a virtual machine? I want Win7 in the machine.

Comment: Updated answer.